# Delete a specific pattern in a Text File

Tags: linux, sed

I need to remove a specific pattern from a text file.

```
check this (2005)
right now (2003)
```

I tried using sed for this purpose, however I receive an error.

```
sed 's/\s(.*)//d' file.txt
```

I want to remove the following patterns from the file:

```
 (2005)
 (2003)
```

The one space character before the bracket also needs to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do this:

```
sed 's| (....)||g' file.txt
```

That will remove four occurrences of any character within parentheses with each `.` representing one character. It also removes the space before the bracket.

If there are several characters between the parentheses then you can use a glob:

```
sed 's| (.*)||g' file.txt
```

Once you have confirmed that it does what you want, add `i` to edit the file in-place.

```
sed -i 's| (....)||g' file.txt

sed -i 's| (.*)||g' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The substitute command `s` does not have a `d` flag.

There's a `d` (delete) command though:

```
sed '/ (.*)$/d' file.txt
```

This would delete all lines from the input that contains a parenthesised string at the end of the line, preceded by a space (which is not what you want to do).

Instead, drop the flag and do an ordinary substitution with nothing:

```
sed 's/ (.*)$//' file.txt
```

To restrict the deletion to only parentheses that contain four-digit numbers:

```
sed 's/ ([0-9]\{4\})$//' file.txt
```